# Restarting activity in spinner onItemSelected

Tags: android, android-spinner

I now have a spinner in the first activity in the app containing a list of languages available and I need to restart the activity to change the language of the app (I am using context wrappers). But my code keeps "recreating" the activity and it never stops:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            Session.setLang(position);

            String name = lang_name[position];
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
            editor.putString("locale", name);
            editor.commit();

            recreate();
        }
```

Is there anyway I can restart an activity from a spinner item selection?

Answer (score 2):

Guys if you are interested, at last I worked around the first trigger of the onItemSelected() call by adding a first_trigger flag to the event listener and replaced recreate() as follows, everything works fine now:

```
lang_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        boolean first_trigger = true;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            LoginSession.setLang(position);

            if(first_trigger){
                first_trigger = false;
            }else{
                String name = lang_name[position];
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
                editor.putString("locale", lang_name);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){
            LoginSession.setLang(0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> my code keeps "recreating" the activity and it never stops:

Be carefull while setting onItemSelection listener. Set your listener only after initializing the spinner, otherwise when you set the default item , it will execute the `onItemSelected` and will keep recreating the activity as per your code.

Comment: Wow. Brilliant answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading, but this segment of code is actually placed after all other initialization (including setting default item) of my spinner... @@

Comment: I think that the problem may still occur even if the code is placed after. If I recall correctly you can get around this initial triggering of the event by using a runnable to set the listener (which I believe can cause issues) or by setting  the 2nd parameter (animate)  of `setPosition` to false. This may be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219652/how-to-stop-onitemselected-from-firing-off-multiple-times-after-a-selection-of

Comment: I sorted out a solution finally, please check it out if you are interested. Thanks everyone for helping.